# webpack-dev-server electron multithreading

Tags: multithreading, webpack, electron, webpack-dev-server

Looking to better understand the way to approach my desired goal.  Building an electron application that will perform processor intense tasks.  I would like to utilize multithreaded design using the approach of creating a hidden BrowserWindow() for each task.

I am currently using electron-webpack and webpack-dev-serve for development.  I am having limited success at the moment.  What would be the best/cleanest way to have the following architecture that runs both in development and production mode.

[Desired Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXrNR.png)

I currently have main.js and renderer.js working well.  Now I am attempting to run additional BrowserWindows that will perform more processor intensive task, but I am not sure on how to get this working.  I did find a good example [here](https://github.com/sgdan/electron-background-processing) of electron background processing, but this does not involve using electron-webpack and webpack-dev-serve.

I was thinking to have my src code like this

```
src/common/task1/
  - task1.html
  - task1.js
src/common/task2/
  - task2.html
  - task2.js
```

In my main.js (production) I would have:

```
let bg = new BrowserWindow({ show: false })
bg.loadURL(url.format({
  pathname:  path.join(__dirname, 'common/task1/task1.html'),
  protocol: 'file',
  slashes: true
}))
```

currently, I can see common/* bundled in my app.asar.  However, it does not seem to load the task1.html file.  I have the BrowserWindow set `show: true`.  So I do see the window and I don't see any errors.  However, my `<h1>` tag to prove the html is loaded is not showing in the window.  I don't need any HTML to display, because the window should be hidden and I only wish to use the window to run processor intensive javascript code.

Comment: Did you ever find what you were looking for?

Comment: My final solution was to add additional entries into the webpack config (https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/), then directly reference the resulting file using loadUrl().